# How to find distinct columns in a nested subquery in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I need to find the distinct drinkers that ordered 'VODKA' and 'WHISKY'. I AM ONLY ALLOWED TO USE A NESTED QUERY. No other format is accepted.

I am quite new to sql so any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Here are the tables I am trying to retrieve data from:

```
CREATE TABLE DRINKERS ( /* All drinkers */
DRINKER VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DRINKERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (DRINKER));

CREATE TABLE ORDERS(    /* Drinkers visit pubs and consumes drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
ODATE       DATE        NOT NULL,   /* Order date   */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
DRINK_NO    DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL,   /* A sequence number of a drink */
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, PUB, ODATE, DRINK, DRINK_NO),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(PUB, DRINK) REFERENCES SERVES(PUB, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER)   );
```

Here is my SELECT statement so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DRINKER
FROM DRINKERS
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DRINKER 
              FROM ORDERS
              WHERE DRINKERS.DRINKER = ORDERS.DRINKER
              AND DRINK = 'VODKA' AND 'WHISKY');
```

INSERT STATEMENTS:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('8-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('8-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('9-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('11-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('13-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('14-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('14-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('14-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('15-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('16-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('17-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('18-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('18-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('18-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('18-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('01-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('02-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('03-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('05-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('06-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('15-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LITTLE PIRATE', STR_TO_DATE('16-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'CHAMPAGNE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LITTLE PIRATE', STR_TO_DATE('17-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'CHAMPAGNE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('20-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('22-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('01-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('05-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('01-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('02-MAY-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAY-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-MAY-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('01-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('02-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('8-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('9-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('11-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JUL-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('13-JUL-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('14-AUG-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);

INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('11-JAN-2020','%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('09-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 6);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 7);

INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR- 2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('05-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('24-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);

INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('13-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 6);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('04-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('15-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);

INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020','%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'COGNAC', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'COGNAC', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'COGNAC', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LITTLE PIRATE', STR_TO_DATE('03- MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'SWEET DREAMS', STR_TO_DATE('23-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('14-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('06-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('23-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('09-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LITTLE PIRATE', STR_TO_DATE('04-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'VODKA', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);

INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('15-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('15-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('19-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('05-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('20-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('15-APR- 2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('16-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('17-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
DRINKER 

SERGIEY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an hanving for count distinct drink  group by DRINKER

```
SELECT DRINKERS.DRINKER
FROM DRINKERS
INNER JOIN ORDERS DRINKERS.DRINKER = ORDERS.DRINKER
WHERE ORDERS.DRINK IN ( 'VODKA' , 'WHISKY')
GROUP BY DRINKER
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ORDERS.DRINK ) = 2
```

or if you need a nested

```
    SELECT DISTINCT DRINKER
    FROM DRINKERS
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DRINKER 
                  FROM ORDERS
                  WHERE DRINK IN ( 'VODKA' AND 'WHISKY')
                  GROUP BY DRINKER
                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ORDERS.DRINK ) = 2 
                  );
```

Comment: It has to be a nested query

Comment: It is in the question, at the top, in capital letters

Comment: @Noods  i'm not in your data  . so you should update your question add  a proper clear data sample and the expected  result  ..  as tabular text.

Comment: Updated with insert statements and desired output

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you want. In the inner query you get two lines for a drinker if they drank both VODKA and WHISKY otherwise you get 1 or 0.

The HAVING COUNT(*)=2 just returns those that had both. Then you just get the distinct DRINKER list.

Since the DRINKER column appears in the ORDERS table, you do not need to reference the DRINKERS table at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DRINKER
FROM (SELECT DRINKER, COUNT(*)
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DRINKER, DRINK 
                   FROM ORDERS
                   WHERE DRINK IN("VODKA","WHISKY"))
      GROUP BY DRINKER
      HAVING COUNT(*)=2)
```